# Passing data between two viewControllers fail

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass data from categoriesTableViewController to quotesContentViewController.Here is the code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let DestViewController : quotesContentsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! quotesContentsViewController

    let categoryString = sender?.titleLabel!!.text
    let quotesContentURLString = "http://quotes.rest/qod.json?category=" + categoryString!

    if let quotesContentURL = NSURL(string: quotesContentURLString) {
        self.updateQuotesContentFeed(quotesContentURL, completion: {(feed) -> Void in
            //print(feed!.item.imageURL)*
            DestViewController.feed = feed!
            DestViewController.author.text = feed!.item.author
            DestViewController.quotes.text = feed!.item.quotes
            DestViewController.imageURLString = feed!.item.imageURL

            //print ("updateQuotesContentFeed")*
            //print(DestViewController.imageURLString)*
        })
    }

}
```

`DestViewController.author.text` and `DestViewController.quotes.text` are passed to `quotesContentViewController` successfully,but `DestViewController.imageURLString` failed.  **`print(DestViewController.imageURLString)` printed out exactly what I want.**(That's why I thought it should have been passed successfully)

Now the code of `quotesContentViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class quotesContentsViewController: UIViewController {

    var feed: quotesContentFeed?

    var urlSession: NSURLSession!

    weak var dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?

    var imageURLString: String!

    @IBOutlet var quotes: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var author: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        //let request = NSURLRequest(URL: self.imageURL!)

        //dataTask = self.urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error) -> Void //in
            //NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                //if error == nil && data != nil {
                    //let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    //self.backgroundImage.image = image
                //}
            //})
        //}
        print("viewDidLoad")
        print(self.imageURLString)


        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

When I run it ,it throw an error`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.You can have a look at the screenshot of the error below.[image]

Comment: inside your prepareSegue is an asynchronous block, the imageURLString is received later than the viewDidLoad is executed. You should just pass 'quotesContentURLString' to next viewController and do the request in it.

Comment: You also need to implement optional chaining in multiple different areas. It is never good to force unwrap any variable, unless you know for certain that will NEVER be `nil`. Here is Apple's documentation on optional chaining: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html